# get a String between characters in java

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string like this

/data/data/com.example.MyClasses/files/السلام عليكم.pdf

I want to cut and extract the word السلام عليكم 
by java code, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are multiple string functions that you can use, one possible one is substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String name = new File("/data/data/com.example.MyClasses/files/السلام عليكم.pdf").getName();

    name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substring  and lastIndexOf method of [String Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
String str= "/data/data/com.example.MyClasses/files/السلام عليكم.pdf";
String result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1 , str.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: There are something wrong or brackets missed in str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("\")+1 , str.lastIndexOf(".");

Comment: @EmyAlsabbagh Copy and paste my code. Its fine nothing missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string with File like this:

```
import java.io.File;

File file = new File("/data/data/com.example.MyClasses/files/السلام عليكم.pdf");
String filename = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
```

Edit: even shorter

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getBasename("/data/data/com.example.MyClasses/files/السلام عليكم.pdf");
```

Comment: Can't define FilenameUtils in my IDE